# Nuxt 3 and @nuxtjs/i18n

Tags: internationalization, nuxtjs3

I would like to provide you with some advice.
Using Nuxt 3 and @nuxtjs/i18n. Have a file called **services/brand.ts**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'

export function getBrands() {
const brands = ref([
{
headline: this.$t('brakes') - NOT WORKING
headline: t('brakes') - NOT WORKING
},
]);

return brands
}
```

How can i translate it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're viewing this from the wrong angle.

vue-i18n configuration and `$t` is only accessible from vue files. You won't be able to use i18n without duplicating the configuration, and I wouldn't recommend it.

You can render that string from the template itself, returning only the translation key

```js
<script setup>
const brands = getBrands()
</script>
<template>
  <h1 v-for="brand in brands">{{ $t(brand.headline) }}</h1>
</template>
```

Alternatively you can also use the `t` function from your setup script function using i18n's composable:

```js
const { t } = useI18n()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle a while back, though I was using Nuxt 3 and Vuetify 3, and I had configured i18n as an adapter for Vuetify. In order to be able to use the translate function, I created a file for i18n configuration, imported the file inside Vuetify plugin definition, and used it as the adapter.

i18n.ts:

```js
import {createI18n} from "vue-i18n";
import messages from "./messages";

const i18n = createI18n({
    legacy: false,
    locale: 'en',
    messages
});

export default i18n;
```

vuetify.ts

```js
import i18n from "./i18n";
import {useI18n} from "vue-i18n";
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const config: VuetifyOptions = {
        components, directives,
        locale: {
            adapter: createVueI18nAdapter({i18n, useI18n})
        }
    }
    const vuetify = createVuetify(config)

    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

In order to use the translate function provided by i18n, I imported i18n instance from i18n.ts file, and used it as the following:

```js
import i18n from "./i18n";

console.log(i18n.global.t('key'))
```